# Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk Swap Environment Url swaps environments for git push?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, deployment, elastic-beanstalk

I have read the docs for zero downtime on aws but cant seem to understand what happens in this scenario?

- I have a environment running in production called 'red'
- I duplicate the environment as 'blue'
- I use eb init on my app to push to the new environment called blue.
- My new version goes up and running on blue environment successfully
- I swap the environment urls ( I havent done this, scared, I guess )
- After a while my traffic gets directed to blue and red will show zero traffic in monitoring.
  The question is **Now if i use *git aws.push* from my command line will it push to red or blue?**

If it pushes to red, I have a process for zero downtime. If it pushed to blue, does that mean I have to eb init again?

If I have to eb init again it means

- Destroy the red (old) environment
- Duplicate the blue as red
- eb init for red environment again

This does not seem to be correct at all. I may be missing something. What is the correct way to do zero downtime on ebs? I have read lots but cant seem to get these points. Thanks!

Comment: Can you duplicate you project once more for a small test? Say do a green and yellow environments - non public - just to see how it works? You'll have to pay a couple bucks for the privilege, but you'll be able to find out for sure.

Comment: [`eb init`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html), [`git aws.push`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28706078/86967).